# Mochawesome Report Visualize. (CodeceptJS and Puppeteer was used) I was able to create a report, but unable to view it properly

Tags: puppeteer, codeceptjs, mochawesome

The report has these data. but not able to visualize

[image]

These are the generated report and JSON data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML reports instead of JSON output, that in your codecept.conf.js add the following configurations:

Add Mochawesome helper to helpers:

```
  helpers: {
     Mochawesome: {
        "uniqueScreenshotNames": "true",
        "disableScreenshots" : "false"
     }
}
```

And add {"reportDir": "output"} to mocha configurations that will be something like this:

```
  mocha: {
     "reporterOptions": {
         "codeceptjs-cli-reporter": {
             "stdout": "-",
             "options": {
                "verbose": true,
                "steps": true,
               }
          },
         "mocha-junit-reporter": {
              "stdout": "./output/console.log",
              "options": {
                 "mochaFile": "./output/result.xml"
              }
         },
        "reportDir": "output",
        "inlineAssets": true,
        "reporter": "mochawesome"
      }
    }
```